# java + xml: libraries handle encoding from the <?xml ?> header?

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I'm so used to using `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` that it didn't occur until now that there might be some subtleties with other encodings using the standard Java XML libraries (SAX, DOM, STaX)...

Do these libraries automatically handle the `encoding` attribute in the header when reading XML documents? If so, where is this documented? (It's not in [DocumentBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) or [DocumentBuilderFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html)) If not, what do I have to do to make it work out OK for different encodings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DocumentBuilder` uses the SAX API to provide the document to the implementation for parsing (though the implementation might not actually use a SAX parser), and the Javadoc for SAX's `org.xml.sax.InputSource` says what it does with the header.

> The SAX parser will use the InputSource object to determine how to
>   read XML input. If there is a character stream available, the parser
>   will read that stream directly, disregarding any text encoding
>   declaration found in that stream. If there is no character stream, but
>   there is a byte stream, the parser will use that byte stream, using
>   the encoding specified in the InputSource or else (if no encoding is
>   specified) autodetecting the character encoding using an algorithm
>   such as the one in the XML specification. If neither a character
>   stream nor a byte stream is available, the parser will attempt to open
>   a URI connection to the resource identified by the system identifier.

So interesting cases could include an XML stream supplied via HTTP, with an HTTP Content-Type header that conflicts with the XML's encoding declaration.

Answer (score 0):

For [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) you can use the `Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING` flag to specify an encoding:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
marshaller.marshal(address, System.out);
```

If you are marshalling to a `java.io.Writer` you will need to ensure that you have constructed the writer to be of the appropriate encoding:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "ISO-8859-1");
marshaller.marshal(address, writer);
```

For More Information on JAXB and Encoding

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/jaxb-and-java-io-files-streams-readers.html